# Angular ng-table params

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I have seen a lot of similar questions but have tried various solutions and can't seem to get any of them working.

Function where params are declared:

```
$scope.customers = [];
$http.post("http://api.dev/v1/customers/search", $scope.searchData)
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.customers = response.data;
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,          // count per page
        }, {
            total: $scope.customers.length, // length of data
            getData: function ($defer, params) {
                var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                $filter('orderBy')($scope.customers, params.orderBy()) :
                $scope.customers;
                $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table ng-table-rowselected" ng-table="tableParams" >
    <thead>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers"
        ng-click="cust.$selected = !cust.$selected; changeSelection(cust)"
        ng-class="{'active': cust.$selected}">
        <td data-title="'company'" >{{cust.custref}}</td>
        <td data-title="'company'" >{{cust.company}}</td>
        <td data-title="'address'" > {{cust.firstname}} {{cust.lastname}}</td>
        <td data-title="'startdate'" > {{cust.startdate}}</td>
        <td data-title="'status'"> {{cust.status}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I click the search button all of the data is displayed, the pagination buttons and page count are displayed but when they are clicked they have no affect. I haven't got a clue what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.